# JoinFeature attribute_relationship syntax (arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, python-toolbox, syntax

I am building a Python Toolbox for ArcGIS using Python 3 with ArcPy. I have two tables that I need to relate based upon an attribute. The information on the documentation for the J`oinFeatures()` function has been very helpful, but it omits the syntax for using the attribute_relationship: [JoinFeatures Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/join-features.htm)

Each table has a GUID field called `C_GUID` and another GUID field. The GUID's in this example are simplified, but the `C_GUID` field is the foreign key attribute that ties the tables together.

Input table 1:

[image]

Input table 2:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

I don't know what the syntax is for the "Value Table" that the documentation represents. This is the code that I have tried:

```
# Attempt to provide column names as a list for attribute_relationship parameter
arcpy.geoanalytics.JoinFeatures("Table1", "Table2", "Output", attribute_relationship=["C_GUID", "C_GUID"])
```

Which gives me this error message when running the tool from ArcGIS Pro:

```
File "<string>", line 141, in execute
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoanalytics.py", line 1960, in JoinFeatures
raise e
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoanalytics.py", line 1957, in JoinFeatures
retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.JoinFeatures_geoanalytics(*gp_fixargs((target_layer, join_layer, output_name, join_operation, spatial_relationship, spatial_near_distance, temporal_relationship, temporal_near_distance, attribute_relationship, summary_fields, join_condition, data_store, keep_all_target_features), True)))
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 511, in <lambda>
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Traceback (most recent call last):File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\ga_server_joinfeatures.py", line 40, in <module>
params['context'] = set_context(arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem,
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\geoanalyticssoap.py", line 92, in run_portal_tool
self.add_toolbox()
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\geoanalyticssoap.py", line 76, in add_toolbox
arcpy.ImportToolbox(self.toolbox)
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 165, in ImportToolbox
return import_toolbox(input_file, module_name)
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\toolbox_code.py", line 486, in import_toolbox
toolbox = gp.createObject("Toolbox", tbxfile)
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 388, in createObject
self._gp.CreateObject(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
OSError: The toolbox file https://geoanalytics1.arcgis.com/arcgis;services/GeoAnalyticsTools;UseSSOIdentityIfPortalOwned was not found.
Failed to execute (JoinFeatures).
```

So I have two questions here:

1. Is the syntax for calling the `JoinFeatures` function correct?
2. What does the error message mean? Is it trying to find a Toolbox on the web that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Join Features (GeoAnalytics)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/join-features.htm) tool:

> Joins attributes from one layer to another based on spatial, temporal,
> or attribute relationships, or a combination of those relationships.

and its [Licensing Information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/join-features.htm#L_) says that you need a ArcGIS GeoAnalytics Server license to use it.

You do not seem to be using the ArcGIS GeoAnalytics Server so I suspect that you should instead be using the [Join Field (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm) tool which:

> Joins the contents of a table to another table based on a common
> attribute field. The input table is updated to contain the fields from
> the join table. You can select which fields from the join table will
> be added to the input table.

and:

> The **Input Table** can be a feature class (including shapefile) or a table.

Answer (score 1):

I was using arcpy.JoinFeatures_gapro(), but I think the syntax for them is the same. The fix is annoyingly simple and it took me more digging than it should've taken. Just add a second set of [] like below. Hope that works!

```
arcpy.geoanalytics.JoinFeatures("Table1", "Table2", "Output", attribute_relationship=[["C_GUID", "C_GUID"]])
```